# Create histogram using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following data:

```
ora_data01      484     484     486     490     620
ora_data02      650     651     651     671     741
ora_data03      730     768     769     773     773
ora_data04      525     525     525     541     605
ora_data05      472     547     559     635     643
ora_data06      285     377     404     494     609
ora_data07      267     353     387     453     585
ora_data08      308     434     469     526     581
local_backup    118     442     147     156     136
```

and I want to create a histogram chart, and I wrote  the following script:

```
set terminal png truecolor
set output "moneta_FS.png"
set grid
set style data histograms
set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
plot "moneta_fs_2014.txt" using 2:xtic(1) title "Jan-14 data growth(Gb)", "moneta_fs_2014.txt" using 5 title "Feb-14 data growth(Gb)",
'' using 6 title "Mar-14 data growth(Gb)", '' using 7 title "Apr-14 data growth(Gb)", '' using 8 title "May-14 data growth(Gb)"
```

and is giving me the following error:

```
gnuplot> plot "moneta_fs_2014.txt" using 2:xtic(1) title "Jan-14 data growth(Gb)", "moneta_fs_2014.txt" using 5 title "Feb-14 data growth(Gb)",
                                                                                                                                               ^
         line 0: function to plot expected

gnuplot> '' using 6 title "Mar-14 data growth(Gb)", '' using 7 title "Apr-14 data growth(Gb)", '' using 8 title "May-14 data growth(Gb)"
         ^
         line 0: invalid command
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is your actual script, you have a line formatting problem here:

```
plot "moneta_fs_2014.txt" using 2:xtic(1) title "Jan-14 data growth(Gb)", "moneta_fs_2014.txt" using 5 title "Feb-14 data growth(Gb)",
'' using 6 title "Mar-14 data growth(Gb)", '' using 7 title "Apr-14 data growth(Gb)", '' using 8 title "May-14 data growth(Gb)"
```

The first line of the plot command ends with a carriage return, which is the command delimiter, and thus GNUPlot has no idea what to do with the second line.  You can either (a) merge these into a single line, or (b) use backslashes (`\`) to spread your command over multiple lines:

```
plot "moneta_fs_2014.txt" using 2:xtic(1) title "Jan-14 data growth(Gb)", \
    "moneta_fs_2014.txt" using 5 title "Feb-14 data growth(Gb)", \
    '' using 6 title "Mar-14 data growth(Gb)", \
    '' using 7 title "Apr-14 data growth(Gb)", \
    '' using 8 title "May-14 data growth(Gb)"
```

I ran this locally and it seems to work just fine.